# How to get time less than 15 minutes

Tags: vba, excel

I have to query reports based on the time given by me.
There are 4 slots of time: 0, 15, 30, 45.

Foe example, if the current time is 13:44, I will use time as 13:15 to 13:30 to query my reports; and if the current time is 13:04, I will use time as 12:30 to 13:45 to query my reports.

I have written the following code, but it uses lots of If and Else. Please help me with some better code.

```
Sub Test()

    hh = Format(Time, "hh")
    mm = Format(Time, "mm")

    If (0 < mm < 15) Then mm = mm - 30
    If (15 < mm < 30) Then mm = mm - 30
    If (30 < mm < 45) Then mm = mm - 30
    If (45 < mm < 60) Then mm = mm - 30
    If (mm < 0) Then
        mm = -mm
        hr = hr - 1
    End If
    st = hh & "&" & mm
End Sub
```

Comment: I can see that you round down the time to the lower 15 minute interval with 13:44 slotted as 13:15 - 13:30 but what logic puts 13:04 into the 12:30 - 13:45 slot? For that matter, why is the 12:30 - 13:45 slot 1 hour and 15 minutes?

Comment: As with @Jeeped, I don't understand the logic of how you derive the slots from the given time, but suggest you use the `Select Case` construct which may better suit your logic.

Comment: sorry my mistake it 12:30 - 12:45. sorry. and i have rounded to lower 15 minute interval and also nearest to slot (0,15,30,45) to which it belongs after roundoff

Comment: In your question, provide a representative set of inputs, and desired outputs

Comment: VBA is different to VB.NET, which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little maths to round down to specific interval or bring the worksheet FLOOR function into play.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim tm As Double, st As String

    tm = Application.Floor(Time, TimeSerial(0, 15, 0))
    st = Format(tm, "hh\&mm")

    Debug.Print st

End Sub
```